# How to search the installed applications and text of contents in new xcode application in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uisearchbar

I am trying to implement the content search in iphone using UISearchBar. When i am taking dataArray as a source of strings,I can easily search in  that strings.But i want to give the list of installed applications for searching so that when I'll search then that application will be displayed in the list just like spotlight search do.I cant understand how to give the path for searching the data outside the dataArray or how can i search the list of installed applications list in iphone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this-

a) Try custom URLs for apps and check if canOpenURL returns YES.
b) Detect the running processes and try to figure out the app name from there.

For details, have a look at http://amitay.us/ihasapp/index.php.

However, keep in mind that such practices are frowned upon by Apple and may lead to the rejection of your application.

Comment: thanks for giving quick reply.But you said that this practice is frowned by apple then how the SPOTLIGHT SEARCH provided in iphone works???Simply, i just want to make an application that is similar to spotlight search.So please help me regarding this.

Comment: There is a difference between Apple apps and 3rd party apps. A lot of stuff is reserved for Apple apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get/are allowed outside of the sandbox for your application, there for you can't a list of installed apps.